# WhatsApp crashing when linking to Web

Tags: iphone, crash, whatsapp.app

I have this annoying issue for which I couldn’t find a solution anywhere. I’ve just migrated from Android to iPhone and transferred my WhatsApp backup. The app on the iPhone 14 pro works fine, no issues. However, when I try to link to WhatsApp web, that doesn’t work (the website is stuck on loading chat page). Also, most of the times but not always, the iPhone app crashes when doing that and the only way to recover it is to uninstall and re install the app (very annoying!). I’ve tried the followings in all sort of different combinations:

- Reboot phone and laptop
- Use different web browser
- Use different laptop
- Use WhatsApp desktop app

It is definitely related to the iPhone app as it used to work fine on the Android one. Anyone has any idea what else I can try? I am running iOS 16.1.1 and WhatsApp 22.24.81 (latest release).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to the backup. If I reset the phone to factory and reinstall WhatsApp with the same backup, the same issue would show up. If I reinstalled WhatsApp with no backup, it would work ok.

The backup was done using a third party solution from iToolab (for which I had to subscribe). If I did the backup again using the WhatsApp recommended method (i.e. use the app 'move to iOS'), WhatsApp Web works ok on the iPhone.

Might be a peculiar case but I thought I would answer to my question in case people encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: A friendly suggestion / reminder that you can still award the bounty during a grace period: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: "move to iOS" need to reset the iPhone, is there any workaround to fix the issue without remigrating?

Comment: @maupertius did you ever resolve the issue or did you let your backup go? I am in the exact same situation

Comment: Yes, as per my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You should file a bug report from Whatsapp > Settings > Help > Contact us.

For a quick solution I would suggest you to log out of WhatsApp, quit App Store to remove it's cache, reinstall Whatsapp and log in again. I would also suggest you upgrading to iOS 16.2 although it's unlikely that update will bring us any closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately none of the above worked

Comment: Also, when reporting the issue to WhatsApp, they say they can't help because it's "outside the scope of their support".

Comment: Have you tried to hard restart the iPhone? Have you made sure that there's enough space left on your iPhone? Do any of these tricks work for you: https://www.howtoisolve.com/whatsapp-crashing-on-iphone/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I’ll have a look through that list. And yes, phone restarted several times and plenty of space left